# (VBA) Call Template-Sub for changing color of an Image on a UserForm

Tags: vba, image, button, userform, redundancy

I want to avoid redundant code in my VBA Project, therefore I coded several Template-Subs to call in a certain situation.

Background information: I have a UserForm on which I have several Images. Those Images replace the normal CommandButton for design reasons. I want onMouseOver effects to take place etc.

I would like to know whether I can apply the Template Sub to all buttons on my UserForm somehow. I don't know how, because each Image has a different name.

my Code so far, which works for one specific Image and a specific label in that image:

```
Private Sub Frame1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Call OnAnyWhereElse
End Sub

Private Sub Frame1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Call OnAnyWhereElse
End Sub

Private Sub Frame1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Call OnAnyWhereElse
End Sub



Private Sub LbVersenden_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Call OnMouseOver
End Sub

Private Sub LbVersenden_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Call OnMouseDown
End Sub

Private Sub LbVersenden_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Call OnMouseUp
End Sub



Private Sub OnAnyWhereElse()
ImgVersenden.BackColor = RGB(209, 20, 122) 'pink
ImgVersenden.BorderColor = RGB(209, 20, 122) 'pink
LbVersenden.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'weiss
End Sub

Private Sub OnMouseOver()
ImgVersenden.BorderColor = RGB(0, 148, 171) 'türkis
ImgVersenden.BackColor = RGB(0, 148, 171) 'türkis
End Sub

Private Sub OnMouseDown()
ImgVersenden.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'weiss
ImgVersenden.BorderColor = RGB(0, 148, 171) 'türkis
LbVersenden.ForeColor = RGB(0, 148, 171) 'türkis
End Sub

Private Sub OnMouseUp()
ImgVersenden.BorderColor = RGB(0, 148, 171) 'türkis
ImgVersenden.BackColor = RGB(0, 148, 171) 'türkis
LbVersenden.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'weiss
End Sub
```

Let's say I have several more Images like "Exit", "Browse", ... How can I manage to call the same Subs ("OnMouseOver", "OnMouseUp", "OnAnywhereElse") without stating all the Image and Label names within the subs...
Otherwise it makes no sense to even declare those extra subs, when they consist of the same amount of code I could have put into the Image-action itself.

hope my intention is clear enough. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So, you're looking for a simple way to perform an action (or set of actions) on ***all*** image and labels on a certain userform?  If so, you could probably look through the controls.  Also, Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Be sure to check out the [tour] as well as [mcve].

Comment: Thanks.
I am looking for a solution to only write my OnMouseOver script once and apply this Sub to any Image/Label where I hover my mouse over. All (4 Images, which will be my buttons) will have the same effects being performed when hovering/MouseDown/MouseUp the image.